# How to keep Measure Tool proportions visible while sculpting?

Tags: edit-mode, proportional-editing, sculpt-mode

How to keep Measure Tool proportions visible while sculpting?

Problem: After outlining the proportions for my mesh with the Measure Tool in Edit Mode, I am stuck on how to keep the measurement lines visible while using the Draw Sharp Tool in Sculpt Mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the "View" tab in the sidebar, there is an Annotations section with a list of ruler objects. Each ruler object has an eye next to it to toggle visibility - seems these default to "off" in Sculpt mode. Toggle visibility back on and your rulers should reappear.

[image: Screenshot of Blender showing how to toggle annotation visibility]